# Prime number Stone-Weierstrass-looking problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Can you show that if $f \in C[0,1]$, and $\int_{0}^{1} f x^p dx =0$ for all primes $p$, that $f \equiv 0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key point is [Müntz-Szasz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem), which states that for a sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ of positive numbers, the vector space generated by the constant functions and $\{x\mapsto x^{\lambda_n},n\geqslant 1\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ endowed with the uniform norm if and only if $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}1/\lambda_n$ is divergent. Then [we conclude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

Comment: Do you know of a good online source for the proof of that theorem? I hadn't heard of that one before.

Comment: @JohnnyApple, http://www.math.technion.ac.il/hat/papers.html. It seems that there is a proof in Rudin's RCA. Search this site for Szasz.